# App is crashing when i try to implement onClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Im making ViewPager with buttons.
Im trying to get the id of button and set onclicklistener to that button in viewpager class.

I have one problem.
I tried something like this `

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gimnazijablbtn1);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch(v.getId()) {

                    case R.id.gimnazijablbtn1:
                        Intent Banjaluka = new Intent(banjaluka_activity.this,PocetniActivity.class);
                        startActivity(Banjaluka);
                        break;
                }

            }
        });`
```

But my app is crashing.

Here is the log
`04-24 20:46:42.574 24297-24297/com.electroniccode.ln.vodickrozzanimanja E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                          Process: com.electroniccode.ln.vodickrozzanimanja, PID: 24297
                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.electroniccode.ln.vodickrozzanimanja/com.electroniccode.ln.vodickrozzanimanja.banjaluka_activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:200)
                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
                                                                                              at com.electroniccode.ln.vodickrozzanimanja.banjaluka_activity.<init>(banjaluka_activity.java:46)
                                                                                              at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2329)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)`

Comment: can you post full activity code please?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/g6LTRGWT here is the code.

Comment: your Button btn1 is null. kindly check your layout file if it has a button with id (R.id.gimnazijablbtn1)

Comment: Yes it has a id.

Answer (score 1):

try this. You were initializing your button outside of onCreate method. View should be initialized inside onCreate after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_banjaluka_activity);`

```
Button btn1;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_banjaluka_activity);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));


    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gimnazijablbtn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           Intent Banjaluka = new Intent(banjaluka_activity.this,PocetniActivity.class);
                    startActivity(Banjaluka);
                    break;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this but app is still crashing.

Log 
https://pastebin.com/HLQRt5Dv

Comment: @АлександарДолић can you please paste your updated code here?

Answer (score 0):

3 simple suggestions:

1. Get and setup your views like texts and buttons in the method `onPostCreate`.
2. You are setting the `OnClickListener` correctly, but you don't need to filter for the view id since your listener will only be called for the view you set it on.
3. I would suggest to make your activity to implement `View.OnClickListener` and pass it as listener for all the views you want to listen to. Then you can do a switch statement for your views ids and execute your custom actions.